# Does Horizontal scaling(scale out) option available in AZURE SQL Managed Instance?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

Does Horizontal scaling(scale out) option available in AZURE SQL Managed Instance ?

Comment: That is where the docs are for. See [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scale-resources) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out)

Comment: Hi @Rohit Pachnanda, If my answer is helpful for you,  hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Azure SQL managed instance support scale out.

You you reference the document @Perter Bons have provided in comment:

Document here:

1. **Scale up/down:** [Dynamically scale database resources with minimal downtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scale-resources)

- Azure SQL Database and SQL Managed Instance enable you to dynamically
  add more resources to your database with minimal downtime; however,
  there is a switch over period where connectivity is lost to the
  database for a short amount of time, which can be mitigated using
  retry logic.

2. **Scale out:** [Use read-only replicas to offload read-only query workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out)

- As part of High Availability architecture, each single database,
  elastic pool database, and managed instance in the Premium and
  Business Critical service tier is automatically provisioned with a
  primary read-write replica and several secondary read-only replicas.
  The secondary replicas are provisioned with the same compute size as
  the primary replica. The read scale-out feature allows you to offload
  read-only workloads using the compute capacity of one of the
  read-only replicas, instead of running them on the read-write
  replica.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Yes scale out option is available in Business Critical(BC) tier. The BC utilizes three nodes. One is primary and two are secondary. They use Always on on the backend. If you need to utilize for reporting, just ApplicationIntent=Readonly in the connection string and your application will be routed one of the secondary nodes.